# Sorted Link List Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to sort a random linked list from least to greatest. I have the sorting part down, but my issue is that it's not printing as many random numbers as it should. It should be printing 21 numbers, but I've been getting a nice variety. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//trouble function
node *sortedInsert(node *head, int data){
    node *temp1, *temp2;
    if(head == NULL)
        head = inserthead(head, data);
    else{
        //Case for if data is less than current node
        if(data <= head->info){
            temp1 = head;
            head = inserthead(head, data);
            head->next = temp1;
        } else {
            if(head->next == NULL)
                head->next == inserthead(head->next, data);
            //Case for if data is greater than current node, but less than next node
            else if(data > head->info && (data <= head->next->info)){
                temp1 = inserthead(temp1, data);
                temp2 = head->next;
                head->next = temp1;
                temp1->next = temp2;
            } else {
                //base case
                sortedInsert(head->next, data);
                }
            }
        }
    return head;
}
//from main, how the function is called:
for(i=0; i<=N; i++){
    sortList = sortedInsert(sortList, rand()%N);
}
```

Comment: Please narrow the code down to where the problem is. There are many ways to do this including print debugging, and uses a proper debugging tool.

Comment: I edited it down to the trouble area like you asked.

Comment: Better, but that's still a sizeable chunk of code. You can't narrow it down to 5-6 lines? Or create a simpler version of the code that has the same problem? Unless the problem is obvious, most people won't sift through that much code to debug your program for you.

Comment: Why do you show `sortedInsert()` when, according to your question, you "have the sorting part down" and your problem is with the number of random numbers you want to print?

Comment: Just added in the creating part. Missed that part when I was editing.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how many numbers `N` is, and how are we supposed to know how many numbers are printed, and where is the printing code?

Comment: Funny thing. I included that, and was told I showed too much. N is equal to 20. It should be printing 21 numbers, but is printing out a range of numbers from around 4 to 8 to 18ish.

Comment: So you really don't "have the sort part down", your question should rather be saying "Help, my ridiculously convoluted sortedInsert() is dropping nodes!".

Comment: I suppose that's a way to word it! Not sure if people would be very willing to help if I advertised it was convoluted :) I'm still learning, and dropping nodes wasn't a term to me until... two minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the line

`if(head->next == NULL)
       head->next == inserthead(head->next, data);`

you use two equal signs instead of one, so you have a boolean comparison and not an assignment.

with assignment (one equal sign) the code works:

`./a.out
0 1 2 3 3 6 6 6 6 7 9 10 11 12 12 13 15 15 16 17 19`

Comment: I feel ridiculously dumb. Thank you so much!